# How To Call Button Click Event In VB6

Tags: visual-studio, events, button, vb6, click

I want to call a click in event from a button in VB6, I can't seem to figure it out. I have tried this code here but it doesn't work.

```
Call cmdLoads_Click(Sender, e)
```

I have also set the sub to public as well, still no luck.

Comment: You call a button click event by, well, **clicking the button**. If you want code you can call from other places, move that code into its own method, which you can then call from either the button click event or anywhere else in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button sub has to have an index:

```
Private Sub cmdLoads_Click(index As Integer)
```

The name of the command button is cmdLoads, it is really cmdLoads(0). So all I had to do is change the code to this to make it work.

```
Call cmdLoads_Click(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

A command button (or any other object raising events) can have multiple sinks (event subscribers) so calling "xxx_Click" sub will not notify any of the other listeners.

In short: use `cmdLoads(0).Value = True` as it's more portable.